Cannot pass another page id value
I'm creating new page from someone project
why i can't open the page and can't pass the Id from here to other page
                onTabRow: (value) async {
                  print("Window keys: ${value.keys}");
                  print("Window : ${value}");
                  print("Window ID : ${value['Id']}");
                  June.getState(() => MainAppTabController()).add(MyTabData(
                    text: 'Sales Order - ${value['Document No']}',
                    content: SalesOrderDetailPage(
                        tablePage: SalesOrderWindow(), windowId: value['Id']),
                  ));
                }),

debug console looks like this
flutter: Window keys: (Id, Status, Name, Document No)
flutter: Window : {Id: 1237846, Status: Completed, Name: Sovie Safitri, Document No: SO-KSSPOS2412020003}
flutter: Window ID : 1237846

this is the page that i want to pass the id
class SalesOrderDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? windowId;
  final Object? tablePage;
  final String roleName;
  final MedicalRecordWindow? medicalRecord;

  const SalesOrderDetailPage({
    Key? key,
    this.windowId,
    this.tablePage = SalesOrderWindow.new,
    this.roleName = "",
    this.medicalRecord,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SalesOrderDetailPage> createState() => _SalesOrderDetailPageState();
}

class _SalesOrderDetailPageState extends State<SalesOrderDetailPage>
    with AfterLayoutMixin {
  late SalesOrderWindow originalSOrderData = SalesOrderWindow();
  late SalesOrderWindow changedSOrderData = SalesOrderWindow();
  final getIt = GetIt.instance;
  late SalesOrderBloc _salesOrderBloc = getIt<SalesOrderBloc>();
  late MedicalRecordBloc _medicalRecordBloc = getIt<MedicalRecordBloc>();
  late ClinicWindowController _clinicBloc;
  bool isCompleted = false;
  Role currentRole = Role.not_selected;
  final int itemsPerPage = 7; // adjust this value according to your needs
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? _attachments = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  
  pw.Text doubleDotCenter() {
    return pw.Text(':', textAlign: pw.TextAlign.left);
  }

  pw.TableRow paddingTableRow() {
    return pw.TableRow(children: [
      pdfPaddingMulti3(),
    ]);
  }

  pw.Padding pdfPaddingMulti3({int multi = 1}) =>
      pw.Padding(padding: pw.EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: multi * 3));

  Future<void> printPdf(String base64) async {
    // Decode to bytes
    Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(base64);

    // Print the PDF
    Printing.layoutPdf(
      onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => bytes,
    );
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    print("Window ID : ${widget.windowId}");
  
    if (widget.windowId != null) {
      originalSOrderData =
          await _salesOrderBloc.fetchSOrderWindowById(id: widget.windowId!);
      if (originalSOrderData.docStatus?.id == "CO") isCompleted = true;
    } else
      originalSOrderData =
          await _salesOrderBloc.fetchSOrderWindowById(empty: true);
    changedSOrderData = originalSOrderData;

    for (var i = 0; i < changedSOrderData.orderLine!.length; i++) {
      changedSOrderData.orderLine![i] = await _salesOrderBloc
          .getSOrderLineById(changedSOrderData.orderLine![i].id!.toInt());
    }

    _salesOrderBloc.updateSOrderWindowData(changedSOrderData,
        isNeedUpdate: true);

    _attachments =
        await _salesOrderBloc.getAttachments(changedSOrderData.id!.toInt());
    setState(() {});

    await June.getState(() => ProductWindowController()).fetchProductModel(
        salesRegionID: changedSOrderData.cSalesRegionID!.id.toString(),
        nameSearchQuery: '');
    changedSOrderData.productListByCategory =
        June.getState(() => ProductWindowController())
            .fetchProductGroupByProductCategory();
    currentRole = await getCurrentRole();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainAppWrapper(
        onRefresh: () async {
          EasyLoading.show();
          await fetchData();
          EasyLoading.dismiss();
        },
        status: changedSOrderData.documentStatus,
        title: 'Sales Order - ${changedSOrderData.documentNo ?? "NEW"}',
...

and if i give the random key in value and it would be null, it can open the page but and all data would be null..
and if i use the key of value like id, status, document no or name, it won't open the page
tablePage: SalesOrderWindow(), windowId: value['bvb']) and this will open the page


flutter: Window ID : null

How to solve this kinda problem?
